# Pasargad payment gateway sign method in nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js

Iran Pasargad bank requires to sign payment gateway request to be signed using RSA private key, following C# code snippet is provided by the bank and it's working, but I cant get it work using NodeJS.

```
public string GetSign(string data)
{
    var cs = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = "PaymentTest" };
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cs) { PersistKeyInCsp = false };
    rsa.Clear();
    rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue>Modulus>...</RSAKeyValue>");

    byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
    string sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
    return sign;
}
```

Comment: Make sure your signing code is server side, you do not want client side (js) signing with **your private** key. Also you should edit your question and add your node.js code with the attempt to sign

Comment: The c# code does `string -> byte array (UTF8 encoding) -> RSA/SHA1` but with no info on your actual nodejs code it is hard to help you with your problem, consider editing your question. Consider checking [related questions with accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnodejs%5D+rsa+sha1+hasaccepted%3Ayes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using following code, Hope it could help others:

```
function getSign(data) {
    const pemKey = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
`;
    const crypto = require("crypto");
    const signature = crypto.sign("sha1", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)), { key: pemKey });
    return signature.toString("base64");
}
```